# get-content -multiple Replacements

Tags: regex, powershell

At First: Sorry for my Bad Englisch.

The Question:

1. I have an .csv File with Name, Email-Adresse etc. of 30 Users
2. I have an hmtl (or rtf or txt) with a Placeholder for Name (NameOfUser) and the Email Adress (EmailUser)  (somewhere and sometimes multiple in the document).
3. I want to read the csv File an for Each Username/Email i want to:
   a) Replace the Word `NameOfUser` with the $User.Username entry of the csv File
   b) Replace the Word `EmailUser` with the $User.Email entry of the csv File
   c) write a new file with the new Content to \UNC\Username\New-html-file.htm

My Problem:
If i only Change one thing, Name or Email Adresse, the Output Works.
If i put a second -replace into the foreach-object part, the output results in an error.
I have to change 5 different Entrys and hope that i can fix it in one get-content | ..... step.

A Part of the Script:

```
$userfile = import-csv \\the-fileserver\User.csv
foreach ($User in $Userfile) {

   Get-Content \\the-fileserver\File.htm | foreach-object { 
            $_ -replace 'Username', $User.Name 
            $_ -replace 'email-adresse', $User.Email

             } | set-content -path $NewHTMFile
```

Problem:
Each line appears 2 (or more equal to the -replace entries) Times in the $NewHTMFile
:(

Thanks in Advance
Daniel

Comment: @C.B.'s answer seems correct.
Your problem comes from the fact that `-replace` does not replace in `$_`, but instead returns a new string with the modification. This is why your script writes several times each line to the output. Each -replace returns a new string which is in turn sent to `set-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
...
Get-Content \\the-fileserver\File.htm | foreach-object { 
            $_ -replace 'Username', $User.Name -replace 'email-adresse', $User.Email }
...
```

Comment: Your answer came first. Thanks, that worked. Thanks to all for your good work in the forum!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this shouild work, and avoid a some chewing in the disk drive:

```
$userfile = import-csv \\the-fileserver\User.csv
$HTML = Get-Content '\\the-fileserver\File.htm'

foreach ($User in $Userfile)
  {
    $HTML -replace 'Username', $User.Name -replace 'email-adresse', $User.Email |
     set-content -path $NewHTMFile
  }
```